# How do I launch an app programatically?

Tags: android

My code should check- if a particular app is installed:

**yes** - launch it

**no** - launch play store and search for the app

```
  public void checkXposedInstaller() {
    String packageName = "de.robv.android.xposed.installer";
    //check if app is installed
    try {
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (i == null)
            throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        checkXposedFramework();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "app not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //*** download and root install apk
        // search on browser/market
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "no app found to handle request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

But it is doing none of those. However, the strange thing is, when I swap the package name with something else like `com.google.app`, it works like a charm! what am I doing wrong here?

**PS:** the try block does nothing, no crashes, no logs caught

Comment: `But it is doing none of those`. Can you describe this more clear? Is that the try block run but do nothing, and no `NameNotFoundException` is caught too?

Comment: it runs but does nothing, no exceptions caught

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void launchPackageOrGotoStore(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException | NullPointerException ex) {
        try {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName))
            );
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
launchPackageOrGotoStore(context, "com.facebook.katana");
```

Just try to start the `Intent` for the package name and catch `ActivityNotFoundException`. Then launch the Play store app first, the last try is to launch the play store web if both the app and the play store app don't exist.

Comment: How do I call this method the right way? I want to pass the package name

Comment: And your code does not work properly. It does not launch the app if it is installed already. Instead, it opens play store

Comment: @user9555243 I updated the answer, tested and worked on my device trying to open Facebook and other apps. Last time I am using my phone so the answer is kinda quick.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code and you are able to check that app is install or not if not then you are able to redirect to playstore:

```
    boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("de.robv.android.xposed.installer");
                        if (isAppInstalled) {
                            //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
                            Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
                                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("de.robv.android.xposed.installer");
                            startActivity(LaunchIntent);

                        } else {
                            // Do whatever we want to do if application not installed
                            // For example, Redirect to play store

                            final String appPackageName = "de.robv.android.xposed.installer"; // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
                            try {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                            }

                        }
```

Function Check that application is install or not:

```
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```